# Updating Support packages fails

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I just updated Xamarin Android and updated the following two Nuget packages:

```
Xamarin.Android.Support.v13
Xamarin.Android.Support.v4
```

When compiling I now get the following error:

```
Error   20  Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v13' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\jbp.ITAI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v13\22.1.1\embedded\libs/internal_impl-22.1.1.jar doesn't exist.
```

I have updated the Android SDK and the Support v13, but it seems like it is not enough. I also checked the referenced location and there is no `internal_impl-22.1.1.jar`. Do I need to copy anything?

Comment: Can you uninstall and re-install all of your nugets. It looks like something didn't install correct.

Comment: Okay so It should be added with the nuget packages. I will give it a go